# What is the correlation between cosmic energy and Christianity?

Tags: life-of-jesus, christian-living, spirituality

At Church (Calvary Chapel) I don't remember exactly what the pastor was talking about but he mentioned the phrase "cosmic energy" when relating to what it is to be in Christ.

I was surprised just by the fact that he mentioned "cosmic energy" and wasn't knocking it but rather comparing it in a positive light.

Are there any connections to Christianity, Bible, apostles, stories, theories, Jesus, etc and cosmic energy and what are they? Are there concepts, such as the holy spirit telling someone something, the same as cosmic intuition? Just diffent ways of describing the same thing?

Thank you.

This is a really good introduction video on cosmic energy - for a reference to this topic:
[Spiritual Reality Power Of Meditation - YouTube](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFgQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWttCv0p6WQ&ei=HlS1T_PpF8Pu2gWUsrg9&usg=AFQjCNGfLTEP54ouLIJFH0MLfZFThRAUQA&sig2=lNnmgn61GunzNnAcgTXyww)

Comment: As Archbishop Fulton Sheen said, "there's only one problem with cosmical religion.  The letter 's'" :)

Comment: Peter, cosmic energy his not really a religion, it is more like a description of how the universe operates and has lately paralleled what has been discovered in scientific communities...

Comment: There really isn't a good way to answer this. By the definition of Christianity on this site, anybody can give an answer that describes how it's tightly intertwined within the Christian tradition. However, an orthodox (lower-case o) Christian tradition has no room whatsoever for such a notion as cosmic energy. Not only is it not addressed, it also runs antithetical to Christian doctrine. But since it's not addressed explicitly, one can assume a relationship. Do you see the difficulty this question brings? It's a little too open to interpretation.

Comment: Jacinto, This is true. What that truly leads me to believe is that we can only find the answer to this question (and others similar) through meditation and cosmic energy!

Comment: I may have been misquoting the Archbishop, but he was talking about exactly what you're talking about!  Can't find the reference on the internet, but I've heard it in old shows of "Life is Worth Living" where he addresses your question directly.

Comment: Although not ***exactly*** the same, I suspect there is some crossover to [this meditation question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/does-transcendental-meditation-conflict-with-any-christian-beliefs). Personally, I'd struggle to think the two compatible. The only "correlation" I'd be sure of is that: lots of people believe in them, and neither has any **robust** (empirical data, etc) evidence of being "true".

Comment: Marc, Christians are called to live in the spirit not the flesh. Doesn't the video at 47:20 supplement that? I am really trying to figure this out..

Comment: I think "cosmic energy" needs to be defined for this to be meaningful. It often has new-age connotations, but could also have astrophysical significance. Without knowing what your pastor meant by it, I can only assume he meant it as metaphor for _something_, and as such, it has exactly the same correlation to Christianity as whatever meaning he put into the term.

Comment: Ditto Flimzy. I suspect your pastor was making some sort of metaphor. Without knowing just what metaphor he was trying to spin, it's impossible to answer the question. It's like saying, My math teacher said that cosines are like a tomato. What did he mean by this?

Comment: Here's another video about "cosmic energy": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxbPwl_KRuA

Comment: I think the people who are voting to close this question and who are commenting here are not familiar enough with "cosmic energy" to answer the question.  I'm not sure if this SE is the right place to ask this question, but I don't know where else it could be asked.  Christian Mysticism is real, but it's not mainstream Christianity.  Kabbalah with a C - Cabbalah.

Comment: Methinks "cosmic energy" is a poorly defined term, which means different things in different contexts. Without the context, we can have no idea how to answer this question. And that brings up a supplementary question: **If you want to know what your pastor meant, why don't you ask him?**

Comment: If God created it, it is not God. Identifying God with "cosmic energy" is (or borders much too closely on) a type of heresy called "pantheism".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give me one biblical example of where any such stuff was mentioned. Sorry for the short answer (:P) but either power is ascribed to God or Satan. I tend to think of "Cosmic Energy" as nonsense, but where it to exist, I'm not sure the distinction between it and supernatural (God or Satan) forces. To say there's a relationship between Jesus and such stuff would be, in my opinion, to imply that there is a third side in spiritual warfare, something I'm not at all prepared to accept.

Anywhere the Holy Spirit is mentioned, it has always been clearly and explicitly attributed as such, with nothing left to fill in. No such "intuition" is found anywhere. Nothin in relation to anyone else either. I would question your pastor strongly on this.

Comment: Sounds like you're pretty passionate about this subject.  Do you have any references?  Just FYI, stating your personal opinion comes across confrontational.  I think you're really on to something that could be more developed.

Comment: I was not thinking a 3rd side, more like a subset of the infinite expanding presence of God....

Comment: Methinks "cosmic energy" is a poorly defined term, which means different things in different contexts. Without the context, we can have no idea how to answer this question.